# How to escape square bracket in org mode links?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to add square bracket in org mode links' description, for example:

```
[[http://www.example.com][ Array[i] ]]
```

Is there a way to escape the brackets `[` and `]` ? Someone mentioned URL-encoding, but it's not compatible. Besides, looking for the URL-encoding of a character is time consuming.

Comment: You've got the link and the description the wrong way round for org mode

Comment: @MrBones You're right, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

I found that using org-mode Macros to insert the ASCII codes for the square brackets works. I have posted the [solution on Emacs Stackexchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7793/115).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that Org doesn't support this.

Org's [link structure documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Link-format.html#Link-format) makes no mention of escaping square brackets in link descriptions.

If you use `org-insert-link` (bound to `C-c C-l` by default) and try to use square brackets in your link text, Org converts them to braces:

```
[[http://www.example.com/][Array{i}]]
```

You should be able to use a Unicode character that looks like a square bracket inside your link text, but I haven't found a reasonable character to use. The closest I found were `SQUARE IMAGE OF` (`⊏`) and `SQUARE ORIGINAL OF` (`⊐`), which do indeed work:

```
[[http://www.example.com/][Array⊏i⊐]]
```